# Get the some data after redirecting to another page

Tags: angularjs, web-services, http, angular, routes

I get data form a Web services : I just specify two dates (start date , stop date )in the "localhost:3000/Person" and i have a method that return all objects between this dates in a table with a column called "Details" , this link show us the details of this object "localhost:3000/Person"/Details/:id .
So I want that when I return to the "localhost:3000/Person" page I find the some data between the two dates that the user has specified , how can I proceed ???

Comment: are you directly navigating back to .../Person from .../Person/Details/:id using router service ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are asking how you can save the search parameters entered by your user on the front-end side (angularjs)?

You can create a service to store those values. Services are singleton and they persist if you don't reload your app.

Store the start and stop date in this service and when reloading your main page check in you have a value store in it.

Edit:
As said by **@Adrian Faciu** in the comment you should use the service to access your start and stop date directly.

Comment: Might be better to store the items in the service directly, since it would need the same collection. Would avoid an API call with the same results back.